# Swap position of div / component with each other in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am unable to change the position of two div elements with each other.
I have multiple input files on a single page and I need to change their positions on click.

Comment: What do you mean by change position? Share some code that you have or something that you have tried please. You can interact with DOM via javascript, have a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: You can swap position of components by dragging and dropping components. See: https://github.com/Postlagerkarte/blazor-dragdrop

Answer (score 1):

Have the items in a list and render a `div` for each item using a `foreach`. Make sure you use `@key` on the div to identify it